# How to Encrypt the password to Excel using SSIS package? Is it possible?

Tags: ssis, script-task

How to Encrypt the password to Excel using SSIS package?

I thought, we can use script task to achieve this. I tried the below code by using the Spire.xls nugget package but the respective nugget dll reference are not adding to the solution.

Script task Code:

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace ProtectExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load Workbook
            Workbook book = new Workbook();
         book.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Test\Test.xlsx");
            //Protect Workbook
            book.Protect("vinay-123");
            //Save and Launch
            book.SaveToFile(@"C:\Test\ProtectExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ProtectExcel.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the same code in c# console application it worked well but not working in SSIS script task.

Can anyone help me on this how to fix this or any other approach??

Script task Code:

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace ProtectExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load Workbook
            Workbook book = new Workbook();
         book.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Test\Test.xlsx");
            //Protect Workbook
            book.Protect("vinay-123");
            //Save and Launch
            book.SaveToFile(@"C:\Test\ProtectExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ProtectExcel.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

Excel should be protected with password by using SSIS.

Comment: Is the third party dll deployed to GAC ?

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, the dll has to be deployed to GAC to refer in the Script task code. Refer to the [post on deploying to GAC for SSIS script task reference](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html). For workaround on avoiding deploying to GAC, refer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/)

I would suggest you to generate exe out of the console application & use Execute Process task to call the console application with parameters, as explained [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/protect-the-excel-files-generated-by-ssis-package-part-i)

Comment: I deployed respective dlls to GAC, its working. Thanks Venkat.

Comment: Hi Vinay, accept this as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future to understand. Glad that it helped.